# "Attribute "title" has already been defined" after adding after adding android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android

I have been banging my head on this all day long, but it seems I just cannot figure it out...

OK, so I add a project that was all fine and working.

In order to "rejuvinate" it I decided to add action bar with the appcompat library (as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html).

Since I have added the library I cannot compile the project anymore and I keep getting the following error :

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Dev\MyProject\res\values\widget_attributes.xml:9: error: Attribute "title" has already been defined
```

The widget_attrributes.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <attr name="display" format="string" />
    <attr name="lineWidth" format="dimension" />    
    <attr name="lineColor" format="color|reference" />  
    <attr name="fillColor" format="color|reference" />

    <declare-styleable name="DigitalDisplay">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
        <attr name="unit" format="string" />
        <attr name="display" />
        <attr name="valueFormat" format="string" />
        <attr name="showUnitInValue" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="showUnitInTitle" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="valueIsTime" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="titleTxtAppearance" format = "reference" />
        <attr name="valueTxtAppearance" format = "reference" />
        <attr name="unitTxtAppearance" format = "reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
.../...
</resources>
```

and I use the notation below when using my own widgets :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:droidfa="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.droidfa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what...

Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
JM

Answer (score 11):

Ok, in case someone reads this one day, the only way I could get out of there was by renaming my own attribute...

Comment: yeah it sucks a huge nut because all the attributes are rolled into one. Google should have contemplated this problem way in advance